# how to get a menu in Wordpress item by item and their own subitems?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Please can you help me about **how to get a menu in Wordpress item by item and their own subitems ?**

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. What do you mean by 'menu item' and getting it 'by item'?

Comment: To the person who edited and confirmed the edit. It does not in any way make the question clearer, nor easier to understand. Bolding a question that's not understandable doesn't make it more understandable.

Comment: I mean  
how to get a menu in Wordpress item by item and their own subitems?

Comment: If you mean to just print out an actual 'menu', the one created under Appearance -> Menus, then you could use wp_nav_menu function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu. Outputting just the pages in hierarchy they were created could be done using WP_Query http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: thanx , but I need to print them one after one using  loop  not all of them at a time.

Comment: Read the second link.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the menu's parent items and their children and grand-children
the best way is to build a custom  walker function.This will help

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function